# How do I check if a ROS message has changed?

Tags: ros, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to write a unit test that tests converting between some messages types and one of the things I'd like to do is have a test that fails if the message's .msg file has changed at all (this is because it's important that the conversion functions be updated with the changed message and I want a reminder to do so).  I'd be happy to just hard code the current message MD5 sum into my test, but how do I check the MD5 sum of the message to make sure it matches?

Thanks,
Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162906/how-do-i-check-if-a-ros-message-has-changed?/) by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-08**:
I'm pretty sure are ways to retrieve a message's MD5 sum through the C++ and python APIs. I'm not sure how well it's documented, so you may want to inspect the generated python or C++ files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rospy:

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('std_msgs')
import rospy
import std_msgs.msg

print std_msgs.msg.Header._md5sum
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3